# Reservar memoria para una matriz de long long en C

Tags: c, array-bidimensional

Mi pregunta es como reservar memoria correctamente para una matriz de tipo de datos long long, esto debido a que en el problema que debo resolver tengo que reservar memoria para una matriz de 2^n filas y n columnas, siendo n una cantidad ingresada por el usuario. Para un n mayor a 30 la siguiente forma no funciona, ya que se muere el programa en el ciclo for:

```
long long aux = pow(2,n);
long long **matriz = (long long**)malloc(sizeof(long long*)*aux);
for(long long i=0; i<aux; i++){
    matriz[i] = (long long*)malloc(sizeof(long long)*n);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente tu código está bien, pero 2^30 es un número muy grande, es 1 giga... en consecuencia, una matriz de ese tamaño requiere más memoria ram que la que un computador puede tener.

Saludos.